# how do you find the url of a github repository to clone, and then how do you finish installing the cloned repository

Tags: github, installation, repository, clone

Having trouble grasping github.

I am on linux and in every tutorial for github I watch people go to terminal, and type git clone SomeURLHere.

1) How do they find that url?
2) Only some pages on github give you really clear step by step instructions for idiots like me on how to clone and install  their software from github.

They might say for Windows > cmd prompt type this, then this then to run the program do this.

In contrast when I look at the main pages and even documentation of other repositories I am interested in on git they...

1) don't show the clone url, and or how / where to get the clone url?

2) don't say what to do once you type the clone command to finish installing it (maybe you have to move to another folder and run another command)

3) they don't they say how to get started using it. Like for example to run casper.js script type casper.js and then the name of your script.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Clone URL pointed red]
Clone URL pointed red. Some useful information can be on project wiki.